# onLongTouch()

Tags: android, java

Никто не подскажет как можно на SurfaceView создать длинный клик, у меня объект движется по сюрфейсу и когда я использую обычный onTouch() оно только один раз срабатывает и все, а мне нужно пока палец от экрана не убрали

Answer (score 2):

1. Если нужно отслеживать траекторию движения по поверхности, достаточно анализировать события onTouchEvent, смотря на состояние MotionEvent (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP). Затем, используя функции MotionEvent.getHistoricalXYZ, можно восстановить линию движения. Пример подхода: [TouchPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html).
2. Использовать [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) с включенным отслеживанием длинных нажатий. Тогда при определении длинного нажатия будет приходить специальное событие.
3. Определить слушатель [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) для SurfaceView.

Comment: Я вообще понятия не имею как с этим андроид девелоперс работать, там нифига не понятно мне. Если бы я знал как там и что я бы сюда не писал